# Spring get files and images from external folder on disk, outside webapps?

Tags: java, spring, resources, external

I have webproject which has images inside src/main/webapp folder. I would like to place images in different folder on the disk. But I have no idea how to manage requests to reach this images. 
Should I create some kind of `httpServlet` like shown here: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Or as I use Spring MVC with java configuration, there is more suitable and simpler way.

Looking forward for your suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the spring [mvc support for static resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources), its `location` attribute is an Spring `Resource`, so you could use `file:` prefix

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file:/my/external/directory/" />
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/my/external/directory/");
    }
}
```

@See [Spring Reference Chapter 6.4 The ResourceLoader](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) for a table that list all prefixed for resources

Answer (score 5):

In my case I placed js and css resources in webapp and images in `e://images/`.
For this case I use two `mvc:resources` mapping

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:e://images/"/>
```

And locate the image of **e: > images > abc.jpg** using ....

```
<img src="../images/abc.jpg"/>
```

You could try also `<img src="/images/abc.jpg"/> or <img src="images/abc.jpg">` (If not work)

The css/js linked under **webapp > resources > js > xyz.js** like below.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../resources/js/xyz.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above. Does not work with any of the syntax combinations. Getting 404 error.
This is what I am adding in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file
<mvc:resources mapping="/imagesa/**" location="file:/D://itm_img/" />

Comment: @techhunter try with the exact slash from my reference of location. I see you use an extra slash before your drive name (/D). Please remove extra slash and lower case of drive name.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The avbove one worked me after changing the extension of image from ".jpg" to ".JPG". upvoted the answer.

Comment: @techhunter Thanks for vote. By the way you can add many more resources mapping and location in your xml.

Comment: Hi how to access this image from browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can`implement WebMvcConfigurer` in your main Application or Main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.your.package.controller")
@Configuration
public class ServicesApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {   // ServicesApplication is my main class

    String your_drive_location = "file:///D:/upload_dir/upload/"; // my file path  

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(your_drive_location );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am using JSTL for showing:

```
<c:forEach items="${ListOfBrand}" var="brand">  // ListOfBrand is a Map
    <img src=" <c:out value="/images/"/>${brand.brand_image}" />  // Showing all image from brand table
</c:forEach>
```