# JSP not loading images

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Agree, this is a duplicate post. My question is actually answered on [Spring get files and images from external folder on disk, outside webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052259/spring-get-files-and-images-from-external-folder-on-disk-outside-webapps).

Hoping I can get some guidance on how to access images outside of my applications directory within a Java Server Page. I am creating an application that requires a user to upload an avatar. The uploaded avatar image is stored outside of the applications directory. I am storing the images in home_directory/user_avatars

Applications Directory:

```
/Users/my_name/Desktop/springMVCapp
```

Directory where I'm storing avatar images

```
/Users/my_name/user_avatars
```

I am able to verify that an image does exist for the user. Using the following (I'm storing uploaded avatars by 'user-id.extension')

```
        Path path = Paths.get("/Users/my_name/user_avatars/");
        File f = path.toFile();

        for(int i = 0; i < f.listFiles().length; i++){
            if(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()).get(i).getName()).equals(userID)){

                model.addAttribute("profile_picture", Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()).get(i).getAbsolutePath());
            }else{
                System.out.println("No image for user..using default image..");
            }
        }
```

I have tried adding a model attribute pointing to the absolute path of the image file. But my JSP page will no load the image.

```
     <div class="col-12">
         <img src="${profile_picture}" alt="...">
     </div>
```

I have also tried something like

```
    <div class="col-12">
       <img src="http://localhost/${profile_picture}" alt="...">
    </div>
```

I have ran out of ideas. My only guess would be to copy the image file and pass it to the JSP?

Comment: you cannot access directly images on server by browser. First you need to expose images thru spring controller so they are visible to the world and then you can invoke them in img src or embedd them as base64

Comment: Thanks @SlawomirCzaja for pointing me in the right direction. I have found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052259/spring-get-files-and-images-from-external-folder-on-disk-outside-webapps