# Spring MVC static resources not loading

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring-mvc application which required to load static location from webapp folder and file system. I followed [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052259/spring-get-files-and-images-from-external-folder-on-disk-outside-webapps) answer and many more tutorials and configured following.

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/img/" cache-period="10000"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file://D:/my-apps/sample-mvc/images/" cache-period="10000"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Directory structure is as follows.

[image]

web.xml ->

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <!-- Configuration location for servlet context -->
        <param-value>classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <!-- Configuration location for main application context -->
    <param-value>
        classpath:application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

But it's not serving any file in the given two URLs.
(localhost:8080/sample-mvc-app/images/a1-img-001.jpg, or localhost:8080/sample-mvc-app/resources/test-uploaded-img-1.jpg)

Testing further I found out that, if I would use the URL with original directory name (localhost:8080/sample-mvc-app/img/a1-img-001.jpg) the image is loading in the browser.

Could anyone please help me to find out whats wrong here?

Additionally,
Servlet container: tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing default servlet mappings from web.xml. [Default servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html#wp157934) is an servlet which is created in every web app. In [tomcat it serves static resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/default-servlet.html#what).